# what is correct way to store & search alphabet-numeric field in Lucene.Net?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I have a field act number which likely have  very random pattern, where they contain alphabets, numbers, special characters. for example **'A-318-215', 'oa/6521', 'IA No. 856', 'Application no 7455'** etc. i want to store them in lucene document and search for it. current implementation

`doc.Add(new TextField("ActNumber", ConvertToEmpty(sampledata.ActNumber), Field.Store.YES));`

to search i am using Prefix query with remove of special characters

```
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery() ;
bq.Add(new PrefixQuery(new Term("ActNumber","a")),Occur.MUST) ;
bq.Add(new PrefixQuery(new Term("ActNumber","3")),Occur.MUST) ;
TopDocs bqDocs = searcher.Search(bq,100) ;
```

but i am not getting as expect result. i am new to Lucene.net , kindly suggest better way to do it . i am using StandardAnalyser.

As andrew asked in comment , actually search requirement is for both action like if user copy paste exact text there will be that the search result  or if user start typing one by one then search result should be according to that.

for example if user typed **"a-3"** so it should show in search result **"A-318-215"** .

i can't use DB because there other many text fields also where Lucene working perfectly but this filed creating main issue.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "_search for it_". Do you mean the user will type in the exact, complete "act number" (do you mean account number?) and expect to get 1 hit? Or do you mean the user will expect to type any part of the "act number", and get all results which match that substring? Or something else? How you index your data depends on how it will be searched.

Comment: It's also possible that you would be better off using a different technology, such as a relational DB primary key search (or other relational table index), rather than a Lucene full-text search (again, depending on what you mean by "_search for it_".) You can [edit] your question to clarify. Also, please show us what you mean by "_i am not getting as expect result_", with some examples of what you expect to get and what you actually get.

Answer (score 0):

I'd store it in a string field instead of text field.  This way the analyzer won't remove the dashes, slashes or periods or try to do word breaks on the spaces.

Then do a prefix query on that string field.

So for example if the string field value is`A-318-215` and you do a prefix search for `A-318-215` it will find it, or if you do a prefix search for `A-31` (for example) it will still be in the results.